# Why does security header is not valid found even my API details is correct?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway

Iam using php codeigniter framework, when i pay by paypal i got message "Security header is not valid". So i recheck the API details but all details are perfect.

How can i handle this?

Please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: If all details are perfect it would work, so something must be off. You are not giving us much to work with. A little code about how you set the headers would be good. Be sure to remove any private tokens, usernames, passwords etc if you are using them.

Comment: Please put your code here